# .exrc not working

Tags: bash, unix, vi

i am new to unix. I have created a .exrc file in my home folder. I just entered set nu and set ai in the .exrc to check. But whenever I'm opening vi editor, this doesn't work.

Further, I entered as superuser, by typing su and password, and now opened a new file in vi editor, now it is working.

Do we need to have superuser privilege to have this? Please help me on this.

Comment: please double check what is actually happening, I can't reproduce this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I think is happening:

1. `vi` is actually a link or alias to `vim`, a modern version of `vi`.
2. You have a `.vimrc` file, which `vim` will read if present instead of `.exrc`.
3. As superuser, `vi` is not a link to `vim`, and ignores `.vimrc` and reads `.exrc`.

Check the output of

```
$ which vi
$ ls -l `which vi`
$ ls ~/.vimrc
```

The solution would be to use `.vimrc` instead of `.exrc`.

Comment: yes this worked... I copied the file contents of .exrc to .vimrc and now it works fine..i just have one doubt...if i login as superuser, if contents of exrc and vimrc are different, which one will be read now.? and thanks for the help

Comment: Good to hear! As a little history lesson, the original `vi` was a screen-oriented version of an editor called `ex`, but it didn't have any commands of its own that weren't already valid `ex` commands, so it just used the same configuration file. `vim`, on the other hand, has a *lot* of commands that don't work in `vi`, and so has its own file to avoid compatibility issues.

Comment: As to your other question, as superuser typing `vi` will run that command, and not `vim`, so it would always use `.exrc`. Even as superuser, though, you can run `vim` explicitly.

Comment: yes that's right, now i have different exrc and vimrc files, difference is that i didn't put set nu in vimrc. i logged in as superuser, and typed vi filename, so it executed exrc, showing line numbers. now i typed vim file2, but now it shows line numbers, indicating that it is still using exrc file here...please clarify

Comment: As superuser, I believe it is looking for /root/.vimrc and /root/.exrc instead of your ~you/.*rc.

Comment: thank you very much for the help...seems unix is not that easy to learn...but really it is interesting...

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that your `~/.exrc` is readable and that it actually works by running `:source $HOME/.exrc` in vi.

If you are using a more "traditional" vi (not Vim), it may be due to addtional permission issues. The POSIX document about [ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) says:

> Historically, the 4 BSD ex and vi read the $HOME and local .exrc files if they were owned by the real ID of the user, or the sourceany option was set, regardless of other considerations. This was a security problem because it is possible to put normal UNIX system commands inside a .exrc file. POSIX.1-2017 does not specify the sourceany option, and historical implementations are encouraged to delete it.

Make sure you are the owner of `~/.exrc`: `chown <your-username> ~/.exrc`

In addition, if you happen to be using [ex-vi](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net) ("Traditional vi"), `~/.exrc` must not be group- or world-writable. Run `chmod go-w ~/.exrc` to ensure this. Reference from the changelog of the 09/23/00 release:

> - POSIX.2: If .exrc files are world or group writeable, they are ignored
>   unless "sourceany" is set.